# ERROR: While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

I tried to install serialport into Windows 7 as administrator
however, I am facing below error:

```
C:\Sites>gem install serialport
ERROR: While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

I've tried the following, but they have not helped:

- [OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: cert already in hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263121/opensslx509storeerror-cert-already-in-hash-table)
- [Where is Ruby looking for SSL_CERT_FILE?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76115/where-is-ruby-looking-for-ssl-cert-file)

I have tried to find those solution from online. However, it still cant work. Any ideas?

Below are gem environment for my PC:

```
C:\Sites>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.5 (2014-11-13 patchlevel 273) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/5004118294/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86-mingw32

C:\Sites>gem which openssl
openssl Directory: C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\ruby\2.1.0\openssl.rb
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRy this in your command line

```
ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
```

Also see [OpenSSL::X509::StoreError: cert already in hash table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23263121) and [SSL Error When installing rubygems, Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19150017).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have tried this solution before. However, It cannot work in my environment.
 
'C:\Sites>ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE'
C:/Users/Luis/Code/luislavena/knap-build/var/knapsack/software/x86-windows/opens
sl/1.0.0o/ssl/cert.pem'

Thanks

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150017/ssl-error-when-installing-rubygems-unable-to-pull-data-from-https-rubygems-o

Comment: Hi @Nitin Rajan. It works now when I update the gem to 2.4.5. Thanks a lot... ^^

Answer (score 1):

May be the "SSL_CERT_FILE" environment variable is wrong. Just delete the variable and try.

Answer (score 0):

TO fix this error I just added the SSL_CERT_FILE variable in my System Environment.
Type

`sysdm.cpl`

at your command prompt to get to the system Environment.

In the User variables SET the SSL directory and file location to a known ssl certificate directory. I set mine to Git bash

`SSL_CERT_DIR = C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs`

`SSL_CERT_FILE = C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\cert.pem`[image]

You can use this awesome tool [here](https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools) to check if you can make a connection on https.
https://github.com/mislav/ssl-tools