# What is this Ruby SSL error?

Tags: ruby, ssl, rubygems, cocoapods

I've been having SSL issues with rubygems. So far I have manually updated rubygems and manually added a new certificate as in [this](http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue) guide. However, I'm getting a new error:

```
Alexs-MBP:~ alextyshka$ sudo gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)
```

What is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::X509::StoreError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592898/error-while-executing-gem-opensslx509storeerror)

Comment: I'm aware of that thread, I just didn't find a satisfactory answer. I don't like answers that just say, "type this in your command line" I want to know what it does.